# PYQT: Horizontal and Vertical Headers

Tags: python, qt, header, pyqt, qtableview

Does anyone know how to add vertical and horizontal headers to a QTableView? I have been working on this for several hours now, and I can't seem to figure it out. 
Current Result:
[image]

However, I am trying to produce this: (Sorry, I did it in excel -- however, I hope you get the idea).
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import sys
try:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
except ImportError:
    QString = str

SYSTEM=0

class inovaTableModel( QtCore.QAbstractTableModel ):
    def __init__(self, data = [[]], headers=[], parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent )
        self.__data = data
        self.__headers = headers

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row( )
            column = index.column( )
            return self.__data[row][column]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            row = index.row( )
            column = index.column( )
            return self.__data[row][column]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row( )
            column = index.column( )
            return self.__data[row][column]


    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role ==QtCore.Qt.EditRole:

            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return self.__data[row][column]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:

            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QString("X","Y","Z")
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return QString("List ") + QString(section)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle( "plastique" )

    data = ["one", "two", "three",]
    tableData_alpha = [
                 ["5","1"],
                 ["10", "3"],
                 ]


    headers = ["Y", "X", "Z"]
    model = inovaTableModel(tableData_alpha)

    tableView = QtGui.QTableView()
    tableView.show()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I added headerData to the model-class. I am able to get the vertical headers to work, but not the Horizontal. Here is the Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header data is per column/row, so you have to return the header for specific section, rather than all 3. The `str("X", "Y", "Z")` is not valid use of `str`, you need to return just the one identified by value of `section`:

```
def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return ["X", "Y", "Z"][section]
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            return QString("List ") + QString(section)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using model-view programming. Also, my code is posted in the original post. I tried using setHeaderData on the model class; however, it's not working.

Comment: I edited my original Code. I was able to get the Vertical Headers to work, but something is still wrong with the Horizontal Headers.

Comment: Ah yes, answer updated. The `setHeaderData` is to support editing of the headers by user.